# Import CSV file with , within delimiter SAS

Tags: sas

I have this csv dataset named Movie:

```
ID,Underage,Name,Rating,Year, Rank on IMDb ,
M1021,,Elanor, Melanor,12,1879,5
M1203,Yes,IT,12,1999,1,
M0081,,Cars 2,13,1999,2,
M1371,No,Kiminonawa,12,2017,3,
M3416,,Living in the past, fading future,13,2018,12
```

I would like to import Movie into SAS such that "Elanor, Melanor" is the Name instead of 'Elanor' being under Name while 'Melanor' being in Rating.

I tried the follow code:

```
FILENAME XX '....Movie.csv';

data movieYY (drop=DLM1at field2);
 infile XX dlm=',' firstobs=2 dsd;
 format ID $5. Underage $3. Name $50. Year 4. Rating $3. 'Rank on IMDb'n 2.;
 input @;
 
 DLM1at = find(_INFILE_, ',');
 length field2 $4;
 field2 = substr(_INFILE_, DLM1at + 1, 4);
 
 if lengthn(compress(field2, '1234567890')) ne 0 then do;
 
 _INFILE_ = substr(_INFILE_, 1, dlm1at - 1) || ' ' ||
 
 substr(_INFILE_, dlm1at + 1);
 end;
 input ID Underage Name Year Rating 'Rank on IMDb'n;
run;
```

May I know what should i do? I am still a beginner in SAS. Thank you!

Comment: Recognize that you have a data value containing the values delimiter (`,`).  Data values containing the DLM need to be double quoted to ensure the internal comma is not considered a value delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Add quotes to the name of each movie, or use another delimiter. Any data within a delimited file that also has the same delimiter must  be in quotes. For example:

```
data foo;
    infile datalines dlm="," dsd;
    length id 8. name $25.;

    input id name$;

    datalines;
1, "Smith, John"
2, "Cage, Nicolas"
;
run;
```

Comment: By the way, are there alternatives cause:                                                                                            FILENAME movie 'Movie.csv';
data movie_out;
 infile movie dlm=',' firstobs=2;
 format Name $50. Year 4. Rating $3. 'Rank on IMDb'n 2. ;
 input Name Year Rating 'Rank on IMDb'n;
run;                                    works when name occurs first followed by year

Comment: Was the file exported or created in Excel by chance? Programs that export data to .csv will automatically add quotes to items that have commas within them. If you can upload Movies.csv somewhere I can look at it to check to see why it works when Name and Year are swapped. This would indicate that the data changed within the file.

Comment: https://cms.qz.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/9481c-luxottica_presentation_sm.pdf

Comment: This is a pdf of research about consumer habits for purchasing sunglasses.

Comment: sorry my bad. Here is the link https://docs.google.com/document/d/1scDaiTVFjN1N9VTzicFexq5-wZe4tjN4kW_PgnjRbYI/edit?usp=sharing